# Some services hang randomly on my linux server (except VPN for some reason)

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, wireguard, hang

Ok, this is a bit strange. I have a Fedora linux server on which run various services. Some example are:

- Nginx reverse proxy
- Wireguard VPN (runs inside a docker container)
- SSH
- Fedora Cockpit UI

There are many others that are mainly docker containers, but I always access them through either SSH or Nginx, so I did not mention them.

The system works *most of the time* -- and this is the problem. It might run for days without problems, but sometimes it "hangs". SSH connection doesn't work, hosted websites proxied through Nginx aren't accessible neither from the local network, nor from the outside, and the same goes for Cockpit (which is not proxied by Nginx). If I manually hard shutdown and reboot the server (through the power button), it will work again with high probability. If I then check the system logs to see what happened, I see that they just stop at some point and nothing is logged, not even debug info.

Here's the strange part: when this happens, despite all the services hanging, Wireguard works fine! It never stops working: I can also access local addresses (such as router's config page @ `192.168.1.1`) from other networks, so the VPN works as expected. I've also tried forwarding the SSH port and connect to it directly without Wireguard, with no luck.

**I want to underline that 80% of the time, everything is working fine.**  So, I believe it is not likely to be an issue with firewalls, Nginx configuration, or similar. The systems reboots as usual around 4:00 AM, after updating packages.

I do not have manual access to the server in this moment, as I am away from home for another month (i.e., I need someone else at home to reboot it for me if this happens, and I can't tell you what is displayed on screen, as there isn't one), but I really need it to work as fast as I can as it has many of my university notes on it (I know, not a smart move).

Thank you all

## Logs

#### System logs

These are the latest logs of the server. I rebooted the server at 13:30 PM, and there are no logs from 6:01 AM to 13:30 PM.

```
6:01 AM [CROND] - (root) CMDEND (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
6:01 AM [run-parts] - (/etc/cron.hourly) finished 0anacron
6:01 AM [run-parts] - (/etc/cron.hourly) starting 0anacron
6:01 AM [CROND] - (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
5:59 AM [audit] - SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=pmie_farm_check comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
5:59 AM [systemd] - pmie_farm_check.service: Deactivated successfully.
5:59 AM [audit] - SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=pmie_farm_check comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
5:59 AM [systemd] - Started pmie_farm_check.service - Check and migrate non-primary pmie farm instances.
```

#### SSH verbose output when trying to connect

```
$ ssh 192.168.1.240 -v

OpenSSH_9.0p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu8.5, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/efiocchi/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.240 [192.168.1.240] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/efiocchi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu8.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.240:22 as 'efiocchi'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/efiocchi/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 192.168.1.240 port 22
```

#### Other logs

Nothing seems strange from Wireguard docker logs or Nginx logs. But if you need other logs I can provide them.